# java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

Добрый день, подскажите пожалуйста, чем может быть вызвана ошибка

```
java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

при попытке отправить POST запрос.

Код, отправляющий запросы выглядит следующим образом:

```
    public static String httpPostOrPatch(String domain, String postData, String method) {
        String response = "";

        try {
            URL url = new URL(Web.url.domain + domain);
            Log.i("", url.toString());
            Log.i("pairs", postData);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("token", User.token);
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod(method);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(postData);

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                String line;
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+=line;
                }
            } else {
                response="";
            }
            Log.i("http post response", url.toString() + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Ошибка вызвана строкой

```
int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
```

Answer (score 1):

Судя по ответу [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21534175/1646082) проблема в том, что вы не передали корректные данные авторизации и сервере вернул вам 401, но без заголовка `WWW-Authenticate`.

Если же вызвать `conn.getResponseCode()` еще раз после того как вы поймали исключение, то оно еще раз бросаться не будет. И в таком случае можно получить весь ответ сервера, если взять не InputStream, а ErrorStream.

Comment: там советуют добавлять этот параметр в хедер, как я понял. После добавления ничего не изменилось, ошибка продолжает приходить

Comment: @iamthevoid главная проблема в неправильных креденшелах, вы посылаете не валидный токен или же неправильное имя используете. Попробуйте получить полный отчет из errorStream и посмотреть, что говорит сервер.

Comment: @iamthevoid, добавлять хедер нужно на сервере (к ответу). Если нет доступа - оборачивать в try...catch и в catch получать повторно, либо сменить либу (скажем, на okhttp)